# Python remote programming / debugging

Tags: linux, windows, python-2.7, ide, remote-debugging

I want to program beaglebone black(linux) from PC(linux/windows) using any Python IDE (scientific IDE's like anaconda/python(xy) is preferred).

How can I do that? How I can configure the systems?

Sincerly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beaglebone can do whatever we want to do in a a linux PC.
**But it is slower than PC so compile in pc and run in beaglebone via SSH is better way.**